# Why can't I get compilation error of custom concept supplied with initializer list?

Tags: c++, initializer-list, c++-concepts

Suppose I have 3 concepts:

- `ostreamable`
- `istreamable`
- `iostreamable`

Where the definitions:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept ostreamable = requires (std::ostream& os, T arg) {
    {os << arg} -> std::convertible_to<std::ostream&>;
};
template <typename T>
concept istreamable = requires (std::istream& is, T& arg) {
    {is >> arg} -> std::convertible_to<std::istream&>;
};
template <typename T>
concept iostreamable = ostreamable<T> && istreamable<T>;
```

Application:

```cpp
iostreamable auto var1 = {4, 5, 10, 10}; // no error, but unexpected.
iostreamable auto var2 = 3.232; // no error, expected
iostreamable auto var3 = std::bitset<4>{0b1001}; // no error, expected
iostreamable auto var4 = std::vector{4, 10, 3, 10}; // compilation error, expected
```

When I use `var1` with the requirements of said concept `iostreamable` such as applying with `operator<<` or `operator>>`, I expectedly got the verbose compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a GCC bug.

Clang & MSVC reject your code.